What is name of the background graph at the Approach0's site?
I am curious to know what is the graph displayed at the background of Approach0's search engine site.
Here is a screenshot of the graph:

I'm wondering if it is a mathematical function or a well-known graph?
By an image search, I found this site with somehow similar graphs. It says:

Abstract spiral rainbow design element on white background of twist lines
Vector Illustration eps 10
Golden ratio traditional proportions vector icon
Fibonacci spiral for elegant business card

But unfortunately, I couldn't understand what are these graphs.

The bottom of the Approach0 home page has various contact links. Have you tried simply asking them directly?

Maybe @Martin Sleziak can shed light.

@user1380196 Martin Sleziak is not registered for these comments, since he is not the original poster, and he has not himself left a comment.  So, he won't be flagged by your comment.  Technically, you can, alternatively, find a question or answer that he is registered for, and then leave him a comment that gives the link to this question.  However, this may be against site policy, because it may be regarded as a spam comment (I'm unsure here).

Maybe the approach0 background is changing occasionally. This is the background I got now :

That is generated by JavaScript+CSS.
Basically , it is a Square with rounded corners at the Origin. That Square is gradually made larger , while tilting it a little. The Colour is gradually varied too.
When the rounded corners overlap , we get a darker perception.
Spirally outward , the Square Corners are very visible with the various rainbow colours.
Named "Doodle" (generically) with the adjective "Relax" by the Approach0 team (according to Source Code) , it is some artistic generation using software algorithms , unlikely to have a mathematically standard name at the current time.
ADDENDUM :
Here is a Zoomed view to see the Squares near the Origin , with rounded corners , getting tilted :


That looks very much like the sort of graph produced by a Spirograph set: a set of plastic discs and rings with teeth around the edges that engage with each other, and holes through which a pen or pencil can trace out the design on paper.
Typically you'd hold/pin down one of the large rings on a sheet of plain paper, place one of the discs against its outside or inside edge, put the tip of a coloured pen into one of the ring's holes, and then use the pen to push the disc around the edge of the ring, tracing out the design, until (depending on the exact choice of ring and disc) you returned to the starting point, or you got fed up…
The curves traced out are roulettes, specifically hypotrochoids and epitrochoids.  The Wikipedia page linked above has more info, including examples and details of the mathematical principles behind it.
Obviously a web site is much more likely to be generating its curves mathematically rather than by photographing physical drawings, and its curves don't look exactly the same (unless the ring were moved during the process) — but there's a strong similarity, and it may well be inspired (directly or indirectly) by Spirograph.
